# Smartphone microphone physical location

Tags: android, audio, microphone

Is there a way to know where is a smartphone's microphone located in the phone chasis? And it's orientations? Some devices have it pointing in the same direction as the screen (eg. BLU, Nokia) while others have it in the same direction as the usb connection port (eg. Samsung and LG) in 90 degrees to the screen. Is there a way to access to this info throught android API? I would like to influence my app's behavior depending on the direction from wich the microphone is recording the sound. Thanks

Comment: interesting question. I don't know the answer for microphones specifically, but I'd have to guess no.

Comment: There's no API for it. How about using accelerometer sensor to determine the current position (x,y coordinates) of the device - i.e. flat down on a surface, being held vertically up or sideways, etc - and code your algorithm to record sound according to the position of the device, regardless of where the microphone is positioned on the device?

Comment: i need the microphone's mic aligned to the sound generating speaker by the time the speaker starts to play. If i could know where is the microphone located i could tell the user who receives the message which is the right way to orient the smartphone to receive messages on his/her particular device. Assuming that the app has no apriori knowledge of where is the sound source located, it could be another user holding another smartphone anywhere, the user would have to set the alignedment himself. I could design an algorithm to identify the source where the highest amplitude samples are...

Comment: but that would only be worth for one time,the next time the sourcecould be elsewhere, and that would imply to transmit a sync sound prior to the actual data transmission, and have the user move the phone to the right mic-speaker orientation dynamically.